# High frequency voltage generator

Tags: voltage, frequency

Does anyone know the name of lab equipment that can generate specific high frequency currents (not radio/signal frequency)?

Does anyone know the name of lab equipment that can generate specific high frequency currents?

I need a AC voltage generator that can produce a current in the 1400 MHz frequency range that can be manually tuned.

Comment: So 1.4GHz is not radio frequency? Well, ok, microwave frequency?

Comment: There must be a fair number of products out there. You need to be more specific about things like tunable frequency range, current level, power/voltage level or load impedance, waveform quality. etc.

Comment: Honestly if there is then I can't find any. Everything seems to be 30MHz max? Voltage and current I'm not fussed about, not sure on waveform quality.

Comment: If it was called "RF Signal Generator," and if it covered 1400MHz, would that meet your need? I don't know where you were looking that you couldn't find one over 30MHz. A quick Google search turned up multiple different ones for me that go from DC all the way up to 4 or 6 GHz.  Mind you, they don't look cheap. If you need cheap (as opposed to NIST-traceable calibration, etc.) then maybe you can build something for yourself from plans in some [ARRL Handbook](http://www.arrl.org/shop/What-s-New/).

Comment: what search term are you using?

Comment: Synthesizers are really available to to 110 GHz, if you've got the cash.